# renewcommand chapter

Tags: header-footer, chapters

Just a short question:
I want to renew the chapter command, so that I can manipulate the distance between the chapter number and the chapter title in my header, currently I have defined my header as:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\fancyhead[L]{\hspace{4mm}\textcolor{headercolor}{\leftmark}\\ \text{ }\textcolor{headercolor}{\hspace{0.4cm}\rightmark}\hfill\textcolor{headercolor}{}\hspace{2mm}}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vspace{-\headheight}\textcolor{headercolor}{\vrule height \headheight width 2pt\relax\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\vrule height \headheight width 2pt\relax}}
```

now I want to change the chaptermark/chaptername, so that I can manipulate the distance between the number and the title.

E.g. currently it says 1. INTRODUCTION
but I want the space between 1. and INTRODUCTION to increase?

I know this is not a working example, but I hope you get it fast what I mean.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

### KOMA-Script

It is quite easy with the KOMA-Script classes. There macro `\chaptermarkformat` sets the chapter number in the headings and can be redefined, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\chaptermarkformat}{\hspace{1em}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\newpage
Some text.
\end{document}
```

(`\g@addto@macro{\cmd}{stuff}` appends `stuff` to parameterless macro `cmd`).

### Package `fancyhdr`

With package `fancyhdr` or the standard classes the distance is hardcoded in `\chaptermark` that is defined in the page style command. Therefore it becomes uglier, because also the page style command needs to be redefined, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newlength{\marknumsep}
\setlength{\marknumsep}{1.5em}% Change to your needs

\makeatletter
\def\ps@fancy{%
  \@ifundefined{@chapapp}{\let\@chapapp\chaptername}{}%
  \@ifundefined{MakeUppercase}{\def\MakeUppercase{\uppercase}}{}%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}{%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markboth{%
        \MakeUppercase{%
          \ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\z@
            % \thesection\hskip 1em\relax % ORIGNAL
            \thesection\hskip\marknumsep % NEW
          \fi
          ##1%
        }%
      }{}%
    }%
    \def\subsectionmark##1{%
      \markright{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
          % \thesubsection\hskip 1em\relax % ORIGINAL
          \thesubsection\hskip\marknumsep % NEW
        \fi
        ##1%
      }%
    }%  
  }{%
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth{%
        \MakeUppercase{%
          \ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
            % \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ % ORIGINAL
            \thechapter\hskip\marknumsep % NEW
          \fi
           ##1%
        }%
      }{}%
    }%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright{%
        \MakeUppercase{%
          \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
            % \thesection. \ % ORIGINAL
            \thesection.\hskip\marknumsep % NEW
          \fi
          ##1%
        }%
      }%  
    }%    
  }%      
  \ps@@fancy
  \gdef\ps@fancy{\@fancyplainfalse\ps@@fancy}%
  \ifdim\headwidth<0sp
    \global\advance\headwidth123456789sp%
    \global\advance\headwidth\textwidth  
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\newpage
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Now the distance between number and text in the headings can be controlled by the length `\marknumsep`. Also the example has removed the "Chapter"/"Appendix"
prefix (`\@chapapp`).